# Regression on standardized outcomes

Tags: regression, standardization

Suppose I fit two regression models: one in the case where the response, $y$ is understandardized, and the other where $y$ is centered and scaled with unconditional mean 0, and standard deviation 1. Can you clarify the possible differences in interpretation?

```
N = 1000000

b1 = 0.903

x1 = rnorm(N, 100, 30)
eps = rnorm(N)

mu = x1 * b1

y = mu + eps
y_z = (y - mean(y)) / sd(y)

lm(y ~ x1)
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x1)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1
#   -0.001498     0.903022
```

I interpret this as "how much higher is the mean value of `y` for observations with `1.0` higher values of `x1`. It is close to the assumed b1 value, which is expected.

```
lm(y_z ~ x1)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y_z ~ x1)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1
#     -3.3300       0.0333
```

I interpret this as "how many standard-deviations-of-`y` higher is the mean value of `y` for observations with `1.0` higher values of `x1`.

```
sd(y) * coef(lm(y_z ~ x1))[2]

#        x1
# 0.9030217
```

I interpret this the same as the first quantity: "how much higher is the mean value of `y` for observations with `1.0` higher values of `x1`. It is close to the assumed b1 value, which is expected. But it's not the same value as the first estimate! Are they equivalent? What's going on?

Comment: If you mean `0.9030217` is "not the same value" as `0.903022`, you are incorrect: those two numbers are identical up to the common precision shown (the former rounds to the latter).

Comment: Be sure to set your seed before sharing randomly generated values. And do not set $N$ so large that you are unable to distinguish bias from inconsistency.